# How to turn off keyboard sounds in Cocoa application?

Tags: c++, objective-c, cocoa

I have a problem with my **OpenGL Cocoa** application - every time a **keyUp** / **KeyDown** event is fired, a system sound is being played... How can I disable this logic for my application?

I have a bad feeling that for some strange reason my application may treat a key press as an error and play system alert sound... Please help!

Comment: Have you seen NSSound class references? '- (void)setVolume:(float)volume'

Comment: That's interesting, however this is not a static method and I can't disable all sounds with it... My application doesn't use Cocoa audio services in any way...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

add to your NSView/NSWindow subclass

```
- (void)keyDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent {
```

and make exception on up and down keys, but for other [super keyDown:theEvent];

i think it's may sense

Comment: This worked for me.  Return nil in keyDown when you don't want it to beep.

Comment: When you say add this to NSView, you do mean the file that subclasses NSView, right?

Answer (score 4):

For me, the following has turned out to be the optimal solution:

```
override func awakeFromNib() { 

    // Do your setup here.    

    NSEvent.addLocalMonitorForEvents(matching: .keyDown) {
       if keyDownPressed(with: $0) {
          return nil
       }
       return $0
    }
}

func keyDownPressed(with event: NSEvent) -> Bool {

    print("caught a key down: \(event.keyCode)")

    if event.keyCode == 125 {
        //your code for arrow down here
        return true
    }

    if event.keyCode == 126 {
        //your code for arrow up here
        return true
    }

    return false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a Cocoa Class, subclassing it from NSView
2. Set it as the class for your View instead of standard greyed-out NSView in storyboard
3. Add the following to your subclass implementation:

```
@implementation YourCustomNSView

- (BOOL)acceptsFirstResponder {
    return YES;
}

- (void)keyDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent {

    NSLog (@"keypress %@", theEvent);
//    [super keyDown:theEvent]; // this line triggers system beep error, there's no beep without it
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 5.6 solution

It's caused because of unhandled keydown events in your responder chain.

Make sure some NSView subclass in your responder chain overrides this and returns true.

```
override performKeyEquivalent(with event: NSEvent) -> Bool {}
```